# Persistent notification android

Tags: android, service, notifications, foreground-service

I need to create a persistent notification - even on new Android versions.
I use a foreground service with (START_STICKY) to display the notification. The notification is created in the method onCreate() and from time to time I start again the foreground service - just in case it was killed.

This is how I create the notification:

```
String CHANNEL_ID = MainActivity.packageName+".notification";// The id of the channel.
            CharSequence name = getString(R.string.app_name);// The user-visible name of the channel.
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;


            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
                mChannel.setSound(null, null);
                notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);

            }

            NotificationCompat.Builder nBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, MainActivity.packageName+".notification");

            Intent main = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            main.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, main,  PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            // set intent so it does not start a new activity
            Notification notification  = nBuilder
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
                    .setWhen( System.currentTimeMillis())
                    .setContentTitle("my app")
                    .setContentText("my msg")
                    .setOngoing(true)
                    .setChannelId(MainActivity.packageName+".notification")
                    .build();

            notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
            //notificationManager.notify(StaticMembers.notifId, notification);
         
            startForeground(StaticMembers.notifId+1, notification);
```

The notification is shown but on some phone models, after a few days the notification is not shown anymore, even if the service is still running.

What should I do? Is there something wrong with how I create the notification?
Should I check when the service runs if the notification is displayed and if not recreate it?

Thanks

Comment: which device was not shown notification and which operating system..?

Comment: The notification is shown but after some time, I have seen that the notification is not shown anymore. I have seen this on a Samsung device with Android8. It could be because I was using notification id 1. Now I use a nine digit integer